# C# Trouble getting xml by dataFieldName

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contentViewConfig xmlns:config="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration" xmlns:type="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration:type" config:version="8.0.5700.0">
    <contentViewControls>
        <contentViewControl definitionName="ProfileType_SitefinityProfile">
            <views>
                <view viewName="ViewFrontendCreate">
                    <sections>
                        <sections name="CustomFieldsSection">
                            <fields>
                                <field rows="1" isLocalizable="False" showCharacterCounter="False" recommendedCharactersCount="0" maxCharactersCount="0" trimSpaces="False" allowNulls="False" toolTipVisible="False" id="postsCountField" dataFieldName="PostsCount" displayMode="Write" wrapperTag="Li" title="PostsCount" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.TextField, Telerik.Sitefinity" resourceClassId="ForumsResources" hidden="True" fieldName="PostsCount" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.TextFieldDefinitionElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="-1" minLength="-1" required="False" validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field mutuallyExclusive="False" renderChoiceAs="SingleCheckBox" hideTitle="False" returnValuesAlwaysInArray="False" id="isPublicProfileField" dataFieldName="IsProfilePublic" displayMode="Write" wrapperTag="Li" title="IsProfilePublic" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.ChoiceField, Telerik.Sitefinity" resourceClassId="ForumsResources" hidden="False" fieldName="IsProfilePublic" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.ChoiceFieldElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <choicesConfig>
                                        <element enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                    </choicesConfig>
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="-1" minLength="-1" required="False" validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field dataFieldName="CustomerAccountId" wrapperTag="Li" title="Customer Account" example="Select the Customer Account this User belongs to" fieldType="MasterControl.Sitefinity.Framework.FieldControls.CustomerAccountSelector.CustomerAccountSelectorField, MasterControl.Sitefinity.Framework" fieldName="CustomerAccountId" type:this="MasterControl.Sitefinity.Framework.FieldControls.CustomerAccountSelector.CustomerAccountSelectorFieldDefinitionElement, MasterControl.Sitefinity.Framework">
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="0" minLength="0" required="False" alphaNumericViolationMessage="Non alphanumeric characters are not allowed." currencyViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid currency." emailAddressViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid email address." integerViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid integer." interneturlviolationmessage="You have entered an invalid URL." maxLengthViolationMessage="Too long" maxValueViolationMessage="Too big" messageCssClass="sfError" messageTagName="div" minLengthViolationMessage="Too short." minValueViolationMessage="Too small." nonAlphaNumericViolationMessage="Alphanumeric characters are not allowed." numericViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid number." percentageViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid percentage." regularExpressionViolationMessage="Invalid format" requiredViolationMessage="Required field." usSocialSecurityNumberViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US social security number." usZipCodeViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US ZIP code." validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field UtcOffsetMode="Client" dataFieldName="MSAExpirationDate" wrapperTag="Li" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.DateField, Telerik.Sitefinity" hidden="True" fieldName="MSAExpirationDate" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.DateFieldElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="-1" minLength="-1" required="False" messageCssClass="sfError" validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field rows="1" isLocalizable="False" showCharacterCounter="False" recommendedCharactersCount="0" maxCharactersCount="0" trimSpaces="False" allowNulls="False" toolTipVisible="False" dataFieldName="SalesForceContactId" wrapperTag="Li" title="SalesForce Contact Id" example="Enter the Salesforce Contact Id of this user" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.TextField, Telerik.Sitefinity" fieldName="SalesForceContactId" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.TextFieldDefinitionElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="0" minLength="0" required="False" alphaNumericViolationMessage="Non alphanumeric characters are not allowed." currencyViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid currency." emailAddressViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid email address." integerViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid integer." interneturlviolationmessage="You have entered an invalid URL." maxLengthViolationMessage="Too long" maxValueViolationMessage="Too big" messageCssClass="sfError" messageTagName="div" minLengthViolationMessage="Too short." minValueViolationMessage="Too small." nonAlphaNumericViolationMessage="Alphanumeric characters are not allowed." numericViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid number." percentageViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid percentage." regularExpressionViolationMessage="Invalid format" requiredViolationMessage="Required field." usSocialSecurityNumberViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US social security number." usZipCodeViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US ZIP code." validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field rows="1" isLocalizable="False" showCharacterCounter="False" recommendedCharactersCount="0" maxCharactersCount="0" trimSpaces="False" allowNulls="False" toolTipVisible="False" dataFieldName="UserTitle" wrapperTag="Li" title="User Title" example="Title" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.TextField, Telerik.Sitefinity" fieldName="UserTitle" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.TextFieldDefinitionElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="0" minLength="0" required="False" alphaNumericViolationMessage="Non alphanumeric characters are not allowed." currencyViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid currency." emailAddressViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid email address." integerViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid integer." interneturlviolationmessage="You have entered an invalid URL." maxLengthViolationMessage="Too long" maxValueViolationMessage="Too big" messageCssClass="sfError" messageTagName="div" minLengthViolationMessage="Too short." minValueViolationMessage="Too small." nonAlphaNumericViolationMessage="Alphanumeric characters are not allowed." numericViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid number." percentageViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid percentage." regularExpressionViolationMessage="Invalid format" requiredViolationMessage="Required field." usSocialSecurityNumberViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US social security number." usZipCodeViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US ZIP code." validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field rows="1" isLocalizable="False" showCharacterCounter="False" recommendedCharactersCount="0" maxCharactersCount="0" trimSpaces="False" allowNulls="False" toolTipVisible="False" dataFieldName="UserAddress" wrapperTag="Li" title="User Address" example="Address of the user" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.TextField, Telerik.Sitefinity" fieldName="UserAddress" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.TextFieldDefinitionElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="0" minLength="0" required="False" alphaNumericViolationMessage="Non alphanumeric characters are not allowed." currencyViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid currency." emailAddressViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid email address." integerViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid integer." interneturlviolationmessage="You have entered an invalid URL." maxLengthViolationMessage="Too long" maxValueViolationMessage="Too big" messageCssClass="sfError" messageTagName="div" minLengthViolationMessage="Too short." minValueViolationMessage="Too small." nonAlphaNumericViolationMessage="Alphanumeric characters are not allowed." numericViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid number." percentageViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid percentage." regularExpressionViolationMessage="Invalid format" requiredViolationMessage="Required field." usSocialSecurityNumberViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US social security number." usZipCodeViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US ZIP code." validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field rows="1" isLocalizable="False" showCharacterCounter="False" recommendedCharactersCount="0" maxCharactersCount="0" trimSpaces="False" allowNulls="False" toolTipVisible="False" dataFieldName="UserPhone" wrapperTag="Li" title="User Phone" example="User's phone number" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.TextField, Telerik.Sitefinity" fieldName="UserPhone" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.TextFieldDefinitionElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="0" minLength="0" required="False" alphaNumericViolationMessage="Non alphanumeric characters are not allowed." currencyViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid currency." emailAddressViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid email address." integerViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid integer." interneturlviolationmessage="You have entered an invalid URL." maxLengthViolationMessage="Too long" maxValueViolationMessage="Too big" messageCssClass="sfError" messageTagName="div" minLengthViolationMessage="Too short." minValueViolationMessage="Too small." nonAlphaNumericViolationMessage="Alphanumeric characters are not allowed." numericViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid number." percentageViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid percentage." regularExpressionViolationMessage="Invalid format" requiredViolationMessage="Required field." usSocialSecurityNumberViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US social security number." usZipCodeViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US ZIP code." validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field rows="1" isLocalizable="False" showCharacterCounter="False" recommendedCharactersCount="0" maxCharactersCount="0" trimSpaces="False" allowNulls="False" toolTipVisible="False" dataFieldName="Department" wrapperTag="Li" title="Department" example="User's Department" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.TextField, Telerik.Sitefinity" fieldName="Department" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.TextFieldDefinitionElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="0" minLength="0" required="False" alphaNumericViolationMessage="Non alphanumeric characters are not allowed." currencyViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid currency." emailAddressViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid email address." integerViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid integer." interneturlviolationmessage="You have entered an invalid URL." maxLengthViolationMessage="Too long" maxValueViolationMessage="Too big" messageCssClass="sfError" messageTagName="div" minLengthViolationMessage="Too short." minValueViolationMessage="Too small." nonAlphaNumericViolationMessage="Alphanumeric characters are not allowed." numericViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid number." percentageViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid percentage." regularExpressionViolationMessage="Invalid format" requiredViolationMessage="Required field." usSocialSecurityNumberViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US social security number." usZipCodeViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US ZIP code." validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                </field>
                                <field mutuallyExclusive="True" renderChoiceAs="RadioButtons" hideTitle="False" returnValuesAlwaysInArray="False" dataFieldName="MCRole" wrapperTag="Li" title="Master Control Role" fieldType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.ChoiceField, Telerik.Sitefinity" fieldName="MCRole" type:this="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.Config.ChoiceFieldElement, Telerik.Sitefinity">
                                    <choicesConfig>
                                        <clear />
                                        <element text="Unspecified" value="Unspecified" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                        <element text="Implementation" value="Implementation" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                        <element text="Sales" value="Sales" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                        <element text="Support" value="Support" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                        <element text="Technical Sales" value="Technical Sales" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                        <element text="Validation" value="Validation" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                    </choicesConfig>
                                    <validator expectedFormat="None" maxLength="0" minLength="0" alphaNumericViolationMessage="Non alphanumeric characters are not allowed." currencyViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid currency." emailAddressViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid email address." integerViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid integer." interneturlviolationmessage="You have entered an invalid URL." maxLengthViolationMessage="Too long" maxValueViolationMessage="Too big" messageTagName="div" minLengthViolationMessage="Too short." minValueViolationMessage="Too small." nonAlphaNumericViolationMessage="Alphanumeric characters are not allowed." numericViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid number." percentageViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid percentage." regularExpressionViolationMessage="Invalid format" requiredViolationMessage="Required field." usSocialSecurityNumberViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US social security number." usZipCodeViolationMessage="You have entered an invalid US ZIP code." validateIfInvisible="True" />
                                    <expandableDefinition expanded="True" />
                                </field>
                            </fields>
                        </sections>
                    </sections>
                </view>
```

This is part of the XML file that I have, I need to retrieve the information found in:

```
                            <choicesConfig>
                                <clear />
                                <element text="Unspecified" value="Unspecified" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                <element text="Implementation" value="Implementation" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                <element text="Sales" value="Sales" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                <element text="Support" value="Support" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                <element text="Technical Sales" value="Technical Sales" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                                <element text="Validation" value="Validation" enabled="False" selected="False" />
                            </choicesConfig>
```

I have tried watching videos, and reading msdn but I am having trouble getting specifically to this area. Is there any fast way to just grab this area by specifing dataFieldName="MCRole" or even easier?

I am only really interested in the text value of each `<element text = "x"`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to load your xml into and XmlDocument and parse it from there ?

Comment: You should use an Xpath query to retrieve the information quickly. Its quite simple and there are thousand samples you can find on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load into an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), search for elements with the name "element", then get the attributes named "text":

```
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var texts = doc.Descendants(doc.Root.Name.Namespace + "element").SelectMany(el => el.Attributes(doc.Root.Name.Namespace + "text")).ToList();
```

If you only want the elements under `"choicesConfig"` you can do:

```
        var texts = doc.Descendants(doc.Root.Name.Namespace + "choicesConfig").Descendants(doc.Root.Name.Namespace + "element").SelectMany(el => el.Attributes(doc.Root.Name.Namespace + "text")).ToList();
```

**Update**

For more complex queries, using [`XPathSelectElements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelements%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as others have suggested isn't a bad idea.  Thus if you want to pick out views named "ViewFrontendCreate" and accumulate all texts under their "choicesConfig", you could do:

```
        var viewName = "ViewFrontendCreate";
        var views = doc.Root.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("/contentViewConfig/contentViewControls/contentViewControl/views/view[@viewName='{0}']", viewName));
        var texts = views.Descendants("choicesConfig").Descendants("element").SelectMany(el => el.Attributes("text")).ToList();
```

Comment: I would vote up but I don't have enough reputation. This worked great for me. Thank you.

Comment: This is slow and ugly vs xpath: var xml = new XmlDocument();
   xml.Load("c:\\test.xml");

   var element = xml.SelectSingleNode("//field[@dataFieldName=\"MCRole\"]/choicesConfig");

Comment: How would I specify the view as well? <view viewName="ViewFrontendCreate">

Answer (score 0):

Try using the extensive LINQ-to-XML library. You can find some good docs on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), but the below should be a decent preview of the functions you should look into:

```
// parse the xml string into an XDocument object
var myDocument = XDocument.Parse(myXmlAsAString);

// use xpath to find the correct choices config element
var configSection= myDocument.Root.XPathSelectElement("//sections[@name='CustomFieldsSection']/fields/field[@dataFieldName='MCRole']/choicesConfig");

// extract a list of the values you care about
var myValues = configSection.Elements("element").Select(ele => ele.Attribute("text").Value;
```

Note that I wouldn't actually recommend using the '//' operator in your production code. It doesn't have great performance. Use the MSDN xpath documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to try and construct an absolute xpath to your config section once you get a proof of concept working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlReader, something like this:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("choicesConfig");

    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("element"))
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Text: {0}", reader.GetAttribute("text"));
        } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("element"));
    }
}
```